# How to export CMD output to a text file in C# after all the text printing on the CMD window is done?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, cmd

There is a lot of text printed on the terminal window from my C# code, some text is printed by an other app that I ran through C# `System.Diagnostics` (without `RedirectStandardOutput` neither I wanna use that `async` thing) and it printed it's own text and some text is printed by C# `Console.WriteLine` function.

I want to save all of that text from top to bottom to a text file. I don't want to execute any file and store it's text since all the execution is already done and all the text is printed already. I just want to save all of that text to a file at the end of the program.

> NOTE: *The following is not my real code (obviously) but it looks kind of like this.*

```py
from rich.progress import track
import time, os

print("Python Test")

for i in track(range(20), description="Processing..."):
    time.sleep(0.1)  # Simulate work being done

os.system("color 08")
```

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;


Console.WriteLine("Test");

// Create a new process instance
Process process = new Process();

// Configure the process using StartInfo
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = $"/c echo Hello world! & timeout /t 2 & python test.py";

// Start the process
process.Start();

// Wait for CMD to finish
process.WaitForExit();
Console.WriteLine("Test1");


/*
---- Save all of that above text that was printed here at the end of the code. ----
*/
```

I don't want to use `RedirectStandardOutput` because as far as I know if I do that and print the things from the `process` using those `async` things, first, it will not be able to print live updates such as in that `timeout /t 2` part, it's also won't be able to account for change in color of the window `color 08`.

I want such a system that will let the code execute normally but when the code reaches the end it exports the text to a file much like how the now Windows Terminal's `Export Text` feature works.

This is what I want to achieve:

The terminal should work normally no change in how it works.
[image: the terminal should work normally.]

After the all the things are done at the end of my C# code I want to save all of that text to a text file.
[image: what kind of output I want while exporting the text]

Comment: You first of all need to be very clear, is this output directly in the Windows Command Prompt, `cmd.exe`, or in a window/tab of Windows Terminal, `wt.exe`. Once you're clear, please [Edit] your question body and tags accordingly.

Comment: @Compo I just gave an example of windows terminal. The example was that suppose you executed some in windows terminal then you wanted to save all the resulting text to a file so you would use it's `Export Text` feature. Similarly what is there in C# I can use to export all the text after all the printing is done. My question is very clear.

Comment: There are many dif erent 'terminals'. Each may have different problems and /or solutions. We expect a specifc problem to solve, not a generic one. If it's just for cmd.exe, remove the [[tag:terminal]] tag. If it's not specifically for `cmd.exe` remove the [[tag:cmd]] tag, and provide more information, _(probably including the [[tag:windows]] tag too)_.

Comment: @Compo This is not a generic terminal problem. This is a specific C# problem. I just used windows terminal's `Export Text` feature as an example that what kind of result I want to achieve in C#. Let me clear it for you.

There is a code which prints a lot of stuff. Some of them is printed by `System.Diagnostics` `Process` and some from `Console.WriteLine`. At the end of my C# program I want to save all of that printed text to a text file without using `async` or `RedirectStandardOutput`. I've mentioned everything clearly. Why are you so concerned about my example of a terminal?

Comment: It has to ba printed to a specific program though, not every one which can be run in your target Operating System! If you need to access the buffer of a particular console, we need to know which one for a focused question.

Comment: @Compo Command Prompt. My target OS are only Windows 10 and 11.

Comment: Why do you feel you need `cmd` in the first place? Why not just call whatever it is you want directly? You don't need `cmd` to get Std output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Definition of STDIN, STDOUT, and STDERR

The OS' kernel of all operating systems use these 3 main **I/O (Input/Output)** streams, and these are **STDIN**, **STDOUT**, and **STDERR**. **STDIN** is the **I/O** stream that is processing information related to input, **STDOUT** is the **I/O** stream that is processing information related to output, and **STDERR** is the **I/O** stream that is processing information related to errors. All services, applications, and components of the OS' kernel use these streams to manipulate **I/O** information on any OS.

## Solution using STDOUT redirection

In the code provided by you, the issue defined is that you want to process the information provided by the operation of a **Batch** script without redirecting the **STDOUT** stream. The ways in which the **C#** application can read the output of the **Batch** script is either by using **files** (**e.g.** JSON configuration files), **Sockets**, **Pipes**, and the **STDOUT** stream. The aforementioned methods are **Inter-Process** communication methods ( You can check this link for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196178/16587692 ). These methods must be used because there is no direct communication channel between the **C#** application and the **Batch** script. In this situation the most viable method is to use the **STDOUT** stream. You can preserve the console colors by changing them through the **C#** application rather than changing them by passing arguments to the **Batch** script. You can also write the output in real time to the desired log file, but as a word of caution, do not read from the log file while the C# application is writing to that file because it will trigger a **Race Condition** and this may corrupt your **HDD/SSD** cells where the file is located.

```
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Operation().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void SetPermissions(string file_name)
        {
            #pragma warning disable CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility

            // CHECK IF THE CURRENT OS IS WINDOWS
            if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows) == true)
            {
                // GET THE SPECIFIED FILE INFORMATION OF THE SELECTED FILE
                FileInfo settings_file_info = new FileInfo(file_name);

                // GET THE ACCESS CONTROL INFORMATION OF THE SELECTED FILE AND STORE THEM IN A 'FileSecurity' OBJECT
                System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity settings_file_security = settings_file_info.GetAccessControl();

                // ADD THE ACCESS RULES THAT ALLOW READ, WRITE, AND DELETE PERMISSIONS ON THE SELECTED FILE FOR THE CURRENT USER
                settings_file_security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Write, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                settings_file_security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Read, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                settings_file_security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Delete, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                
                // UPDATE THE ACCESS CONTROL SETTINGS OF THE FILE BY SETTING THE 
                // MODIFIED ACCESS CONTROL SETTINGS AS THE CURRENT SETTINGS
                settings_file_info.SetAccessControl(settings_file_security);
            }
            else
            {
                // IF THE OS IS A UNIX BASED OS, SET THE FILE PERMISSIONS FOR READ AND WRITE OPERATIONS
                // WITH THE 'UnixFileMode.UserRead | UnixFileMode.UserWrite' BITWISE 'OR' OPERATION
                File.SetUnixFileMode(file_name, UnixFileMode.UserRead | UnixFileMode.UserWrite);
                
            }
            #pragma warning restore CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
        }



        private static async Task<bool> Operation()
        {
            // Process object
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            string file_name = String.Empty;
            string arguments = String.Empty;

            // CHECK IF THE CURRENT OS IS WINDOWS AND SET THE FILE PATH AND ARGUMETS ACCORDINGLY
            if(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows) == true)
            {
                file_name = @"C:\Users\teodo\PycharmProjects\Test\.venv\Scripts\python.exe";
                arguments = @"C:\Users\teodo\PycharmProjects\Test\main.py";
            }
            else
            {
                file_name = @"python3";
                arguments = @"/mnt/c/Users/teodo/PycharmProjects/Test/main.py";
            }

            // Path where the python executable is located
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = file_name;

            // Path where python executable is located
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

            // Start the process
            proc.Start();


            // Named pipe server object with an "In" direction. This means that this pipe can only read messages. On Windows it creates a pipe at the 
            // '\\.\pipe\pipe-sub-directory\pipe-name' virtual directory, on Linux it creates a Unix Named Socket in the '/tmp' directory 
            System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream fifo_pipe_connection = new System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("/tmp/fifo_pipe", System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.In);

            // Create a backlog text file if none is existent, set its permissions as Read/Write,
            // and create a stream that allows direct read and write operations to the file
            FileStream fs = File.Open("backlog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            SetPermissions("backlog.txt");

            try
            {
                // Wait for a client to connect synchronously
                fifo_pipe_connection.WaitForConnection();

                while (true)
                {
                    // Initiate a binary buffer byte array with a size of 1 Kb 
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    // Read the received bytes into the buffer byte array and also 
                    // store the number of bytes read into an integer named 'read'
                    int read = await fifo_pipe_connection.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    // Write the received bytes into the 'backlog.txt' file
                    await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);

                    // Flush the bytes within the stream's buffer into the file
                    await fs.FlushAsync();

                    // If the number of bytes read is equal to '0' there are no bytes
                    // left to read on the Pipe's stream and the read loop is closed
                    if (read == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                fs?.DisposeAsync();
                fifo_pipe_connection?.DisposeAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

## STDOUT redirection method output

[image: Program STDOUT output]

[image: Program STDOUT file output]

## Definition of FIFO Pipes

**FIFO Pipes**, also known as **Named Pipes**, are a type of socket that use the operating system's file system in order to facilitate information exchange between applications. **FIFO Pipes** are categorised into 3 categories and these are, **Inward Pipes**, **Outward Pipes**, and **Two-way Pipes**. **Inward Pipes** are pipes on which the **Pipe Server** can only receive information from the **Pipe Clients**, **Outward Pipes** are pipes on which the **Pipe Server** can only send information to the **Pipe Clients**, and **Two-way Pipes** are pipes on which the **Pipe Server** can both send and receive information to and from the **Pipe Clients**.

## Cross-platform solution using FIFO Pipes

If the integrity of the output must be preserved, FIFO pipes are the best option for an inter-process communication method. In this scenario an **Inward Pipe** will be the best solution due to the fact that the **C#** application must receive information from the **Python** application. In order to have cross-platform capabilities, both the **C#** and **Python** application use conditional statements to verify which OS platform the applications are running on.

### C# Application

```
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;


namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Operation().Wait();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


        private static void SetPermissions(string file_name)
        {
            #pragma warning disable CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility

            // CHECK IF THE CURRENT OS IS WINDOWS
            if (System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows) == true)
            {
                // GET THE SPECIFIED FILE INFORMATION OF THE SELECTED FILE
                FileInfo settings_file_info = new FileInfo(file_name);

                // GET THE ACCESS CONTROL INFORMATION OF THE SELECTED FILE AND STORE THEM IN A 'FileSecurity' OBJECT
                System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity settings_file_security = settings_file_info.GetAccessControl();

                // ADD THE ACCESS RULES THAT ALLOW READ, WRITE, AND DELETE PERMISSIONS ON THE SELECTED FILE FOR THE CURRENT USER
                settings_file_security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Write, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                settings_file_security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Read, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                settings_file_security.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.Delete, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
                
                // UPDATE THE ACCESS CONTROL SETTINGS OF THE FILE BY SETTING THE 
                // MODIFIED ACCESS CONTROL SETTINGS AS THE CURRENT SETTINGS
                settings_file_info.SetAccessControl(settings_file_security);
            }
            else
            {
                // IF THE OS IS A UNIX BASED OS, SET THE FILE PERMISSIONS FOR READ AND WRITE OPERATIONS
                // WITH THE 'UnixFileMode.UserRead | UnixFileMode.UserWrite' BITWISE 'OR' OPERATION
                File.SetUnixFileMode(file_name, UnixFileMode.UserRead | UnixFileMode.UserWrite);
                
            }
            #pragma warning restore CA1416 // Validate platform compatibility
        }



        private static async Task<bool> Operation()
        {
            // Process object
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            string file_name = String.Empty;
            string arguments = String.Empty;

            // CHECK IF THE CURRENT OS IS WINDOWS AND SET THE FILE PATH AND ARGUMETS ACCORDINGLY
            if(System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform.Windows) == true)
            {
                file_name = @"C:\Users\teodo\PycharmProjects\Test\.venv\Scripts\python.exe";
                arguments = @"C:\Users\teodo\PycharmProjects\Test\main.py";
            }
            else
            {
                file_name = @"python3";
                arguments = @"/mnt/c/Users/teodo/PycharmProjects/Test/main.py";
            }

            // Path where the python executable is located
            proc.StartInfo.FileName = file_name;

            // Path where python executable is located
            proc.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;

            // Start the process
            proc.Start();


            // Named pipe server object with an "In" direction. This means that this pipe can only read messages. On Windows it creates a pipe at the 
            // '\\.\pipe\pipe-sub-directory\pipe-name' virtual directory, on Linux it creates a Unix Named Socket in the '/tmp' directory 
            System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream fifo_pipe_connection = new System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("/tmp/fifo_pipe", System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.In);

            // Create a backlog text file if none is existent, set its permissions as Read/Write,
            // and create a stream that allows direct read and write operations to the file
            FileStream fs = File.Open("backlog.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
            SetPermissions("backlog.txt");

            try
            {
                // Wait for a client to connect synchronously
                fifo_pipe_connection.WaitForConnection();

                while (true)
                {
                    // Initiate a binary buffer byte array with a size of 1 Kb 
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

                    // Read the received bytes into the buffer byte array and also 
                    // store the number of bytes read into an integer named 'read'
                    int read = await fifo_pipe_connection.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


                    // Print the bytes sent by the Python application on the pipe
                    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer));

                    // Write the received bytes into the 'backlog.txt' file
                    await fs.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);

                    // Flush the bytes within the stream's buffer into the file
                    await fs.FlushAsync();

                    // If the number of bytes read is equal to '0' there are no bytes
                    // left to read on the Pipe's stream and the read loop is closed
                    if (read == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch
            {
            }
            finally
            {
                fs?.DisposeAsync();
                fifo_pipe_connection?.DisposeAsync();
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

### Python Application

```
import os
import sys
import time
from rich.progress import track
import platform
import socket

fifo_write = None
unix_named_pipe = None


def operation():
    try:
        write("!!! Python Test !!!\n\n")

        # Simulate work being done
        set_range = range(20)
        for i in track(set_range, description="Processing..."):
            time.sleep(0.1)

            # SEND THE CURRENT PROGRESS AS A PERCENTAGE OVER THE PIPE
            write("Processing..." + str((100 / set_range.stop) * (i + 1)) + "%\n")

        # CHANGE THE TERMINAL COLOR TO GREY
        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            os.system("color 08")
        else:
            print("\n\n")
            os.system(r"echo '\e[91m!!! COLOR !!!'")

        # PAUSE THE CURRENT THREAD FOR 2 SECONDS
        time.sleep(2)

        # CHANGE THE TERMINAL COLOR TO WHITE
        if platform.system() == "Windows":
            os.system("color F")
        else:
            os.system(r"echo '\e[00m!!! COLOR !!!'")
            print("\n\n")
        write("[ Finished ]")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)


def write(msg):
    if platform.system() == "Windows":
        fifo_pipe_write(msg)
    else:
        unix_named_socket_write(msg)


def fifo_pipe_write(msg):
    try:
        global fifo_write
        if fifo_write is not None:
            # WRITE THE STRING PASSED TO THE FUNCTION'S AS AN ARGUMENT
            # IN THE FIFO PIPE FILE USING THE GLOBAL STREAM
            fifo_write.write(msg)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)


def unix_named_socket_write(msg):
    try:
        global unix_named_pipe
        if unix_named_pipe is not None:
            unix_named_pipe.send(str(msg).encode(encoding="utf-8"))
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


def stream_finder() -> bool:
    is_found = False

    try:
        # INITIATE A PIPE SEARCH SEQUENCE FOR 10 SECONDS
        for t in range(0, 10):
            try:
                try:
                    # IF THE OS IS WINDOWS SEARCH FOR A PIPE FILE
                    if platform.system() == "Windows":
                        # IF PIPE IS FOUND RETURN TRUE AND STORE THE OPENED PIPE FILE STREAM GLOBALLY
                        global fifo_write
                        fifo_write = open(r"\\.\pipe\tmp\fifo_pipe", "w")
                        is_found = True
                        break
                    # ELSE, SEARCH FOR A NAMED UNIX SOCKET
                    else:
                        # IF SOCKET IS FOUND RETURN TRUE AND STORE THE OPENED SOCKET GLOBALLY
                        global unix_named_pipe
                        unix_named_pipe = socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                        unix_named_pipe.connect("/tmp/fifo_pipe")
                        is_found = True
                        break
                except FileNotFoundError:
                    # IF PIPE IS NOT FOUND
                    print("\n\n[ Searching pipe ]")
            except OSError:
                # IF PIPE IS NOT FOUND
                print("\n\n[ Searching pipe ]")

            # MAKE THE LOOP WAIT 1 SECOND FOR EACH ITERATION
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)

    return is_found


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        # INITIATE THE PIPE SEARCHING OPERATION
        found = stream_finder()
        # IF PIPE SEARCHING OPERATION IS SUCCESSFUL
        if found is True:
            print("\n\n[ Pipe found ]\n\n")
            # INITIATE THE MAIN OPERATION
            operation()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit(0)
```

## FIFO Pipes output Windows

[image: FIFO pipes output Windows]

[image: FIFO Pipes file output Windows]

## FIFO Pipes output Linux

### Linux OS Details

[image: Linux OS details]

### Linux OS Output

[image: FIFO pipes output Linux]

[image: FIFO Pipes file output Linux]

Comment: Yeah it works but the thing is suppose when some colored text is being rendered by some other app. For example in my question I gave this example `color 08` because in my **real** code there is a python script which uses the `rich` module for loading bar (it is similar to color and real-time updating you know). In that case this your code isn't able to render the changes in color which are being done by other apps and scripts.

Though your solution very close to what I actually want.

Comment: I've updated my question with screenshots, so please check it out.

Answer (score 1):

is that what you want?

```cs
void Main()
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe ",
        Arguments = $"/c echo Hello world! & timeout /t 2 & color 08",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
    };
    
    using (var process = new Process{StartInfo = startInfo})
    {
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, args) => sb.AppendLine(args.Data);
        process.Start();
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.BeginErrorReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
    }
    Console.WriteLine("start log");
    Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString()); //can tace output and save to file
    Console.WriteLine("end log");
}
```

output:

```
start log
Hello world!
Waiting for 2 seconds, press a key to continue ...081080

end log
```

Comment: I've tried it already and this is not the solution to my problem. Thanks for your solution though.